# Normal Equation for logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, algorithms

In OLS regression we estimate the parameters of the Linear regression with multiple variables using the "Normal Equation":

[image]

Would it be possible to do something similar when estimating the parameter for logistic regression?

Comment: I think you're making an analogy to the normal equations in OLS, right? To make it crystal clear what you mean, I suggest you start your question "In OLS regression we estimate parameters by solving the "normal equations" (then quote the normal equations). This gives a little bit more context for what you're asking.

Comment: You didn't do as Silverfish suggested, since you didn't then quote the normal equations.

Comment: see chapter 3.2.1 of this link http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c3.pdf